# Ionic Increment Firestore Value

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering if there was a way to increment a value in Firestore with Ionic. For example, a like button and when clicked a field value 'likes' adds +1 onto the existing value.

I saw examples with 'transactions' where this is done but it was with the Realtime Database rather than the Cloud Firestore. I looked further and could not find any documentation regarding Firestore.

Is there anyway to pull this off without pulling the existing value from the snapshot first?

Thanks,
Troy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no server-side increment operators in Firestore. To increase an existing value, your app will first need to read that value.

For an example of using a transaction in Firestore, see [updating data with transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) in the Firestore documentation. This literally shows how to add 1 to a field.

Comment: Thank you! I had just stumbled upon accessing Firestore without the angularfire2 plugin and this is just what I needed.