# Ionic firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment() function giving error

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use the Firebase increment function and it's giving me an error. I am using Ionic 5.2.7.

Here is my import statement for firebase

`import { firebase } from '@firebase/app';`

(if I try to import from firebase like - import { firebase } from 'firebase/app'; - the import fails, so I can't do that.)

My error is on the increment statement:

`const itemsCount = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);`

The error is: "Property 'firestore' does not exist on type 'FirebaseNamespace'."

Comment: Did you also `import '@firebase/firestore`? In fact, as far as I can see you should import `import firebase from 'firebase/app'; import 'firebase/firestore'` so without the `@` prefix.

Comment: Have you also checked similar questions of the community? [1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61189443/firebase-firestore-increment-fieldvalue-does-not-increment [2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499829/ionic-increment-firestore-value  [3] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543067/firestore-increment-fieldvalue

Comment: I finally found the solution. I needed to change the import statement as follows: import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';  I am still getting used to the different syntax on import statements. Thanks all for the feedback

Comment: I have just re-posted your comment as a community week answer. This will not give me reputation; just to give it more visibility in case has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

I needed to change the import statement as follows:

```
 import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
```